Any way to open settings app at a root page?
I am trying to create a ux shortcut in my app that should go to a root page of settings app. Furthest I was able to get was to use URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) which opens settings page, but for my app specifically, which is not exactly what I am after.
I know apple has not way to open specific settings page for say Health app (which would be ideal for my use case), but is there at least a way to open settings app at it's root / home page and then have some text guiding user of where to go?

"App-Prefs:HEALTH" technically is the URL for the health app settings, so you can use that, at the risk of getting rejected from the App Store.

Thank you, looks like this no longer works on ios 18 (there, it simply opens settings app on whatever last page it was)

"Officially", via a plain reading of the documentation, the answer is no.
Here's the relevant section of the UIApplication

Deep linking to custom settings
class let openSettingsURLString: String
The URL string you use to deep link to your app’s custom
settings in the Settings app.


static let openNotificationSettingsURLString: String
The URL string you use to deep link to your app’s notification settings in the Settings app.


let UIApplicationOpenNotificationSettingsURLString: String
A constant that
provides the URL string you use to deep link to your app’s
notification settings in the Settings app.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication
Apple provides an app a way of accessing the app's permissions, because users often have jumped to the same panel via the one-time "purpose string" UX, for getting access to photos, contacts, calendars, etc.
Starting with iOS 15.4, they added support for an apps to display their notification settings as well.
I also found some Swift UI docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settings
(but haven't tried this myself).

I think the general theme makes sense, Apple not only wants an app's settings to be segregated in UI away from the app to avoid clutter, but it also lets them provide a consistent place for the app's permission to device-managed data sources (and permissions).
If they allowed your app to point to other app settings, it would have to let your app have some other-app-discovery, which would likely be insecure, and also, that would create the possibility that developers would write a lot of phishy features like: "MyGOATPhotoApp sees you have Instagram, why don't you go in there and turn off all these settings..."
